# Where can I find Intellij configuration file about color scheme, syntax highlighting and other settings?

Tags: configuration, intellij-idea, configuration-files

I know these files exist because I remember editing one a long time ago but I can't remember what I was editing through these files at that time nor where they were located.

Neither do I know how much config can actually be modified manually.

I know the menus and stuff in Intellij settings but for instance they do not provide any means to add a new rule for code highlighting I think. So does this seem possible somehow ?

Where are the configuration files ? Where is the one about colors, fonts and schemes ? Can we add new rules ?

Thanks in advance